# Why does AutoCAD throw a fatal error when I try to read line start and end points?

Tags: c#, fatal-error, autocad, autocad-plugin

I am writing a plug in to pull as much data out of a CAD as possible.  The main issue I am having right now is when I try to access StartPoint.X, for example, the script fails without catching an exception with "FATAL ERROR: Unhandled Access Violation Reading 0xffffffff at d8e176b4h."  Depending on what I try to access, the memory location and whatever the second number change.  Example:

```
    foreach (Objects o in globalListOfObjs)
        {
            string type = o.obj.GetType().ToString().Split('.').Last();

            if (type == "Line")
            {
                try
                {
                    Line l = (Line)o.obj;
                    if (l != null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Not Null!");
                        MessageBox.Show(l.StartPoint.X.ToString());
                    }
                    //listOfLines.Add(new LinkLines(lx1, ly1, lx2, ly2, Guid.NewGuid()));
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
                }

            }
       }
```

Comment: did you check `o.obj.GetType().ToString().Split('.').Last();`?  Maybe something is going wrong with some of the data.

Comment: I have taken out the l.startpoint.X and it will run all the way through.  I don't know if it maybe wants me to unfreeze the layer or set the obj to be readable or something in order to read it?

Comment: You need to open a transaction and then open the line object (for read or write) before you can see the StartPoint values.

Comment: I pulled the objects into a list from an open transaction, then was accessing them.  Would that maybe be the cause? @JamesDowthwaite

Comment: Try locking the document `using(var docloc = doc.LockDocument ())`. Put that above your foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object can be safely accessed only if the transaction used to open the object is still active. If you need to store a reference to an object, store the ObjectId and start a new transaction if you need to access the object properties.

Comment: Rather than gathering all the objects, then translating them, I translated the objects within the transaction, then stored them using custom objects.  Thanks for the suggestion, worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Does your code is running in the main thread? AutoCAD does not support multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public void getStartPoint(Transaction oTr, ObjectId oId)
{
    try {
        Line oLn = (Line)oTr.GetObject(oId, OpenMode.ForRead);

        if (oLn != null) {
            Interaction.MsgBox(oLn.StartPoint.X.ToString);
        }

    } catch (System.Exception ex) {
        Interaction.MsgBox(ex.StackTrace, (MsgBoxStyle)MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, ex.Message);
    }
}
```